# Prove that there is only one global solution to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ODE

$$y\left(x\right)=\frac{x-ay'\left(x\right)}{1+b y'\left(x\right)^{2}},$$

where $a,b>0$ (a d'Alembert's / Lagrange equation).

Let $k>0$ denote the unique solution to $bk^{3}+k-1=0$. Then, conjecturing a linear solution to the ODE, we find that this ODE has a unique, global solution given the boundary condition $y(0)=-\frac{ak}{1+bk^{2}}$.

I would like to show that for any other boundary condition, any smooth solution to the ODE is not global. This appears to be true numerically -- solutions converge to imaginary values of y -- but I am not sure how to prove this.

Comment: This is a paradigm question.

Comment: Hmm, this is not what I find using Matlab. For $a=b=1$, given initial conditions in that range, the solution leads to imaginary values for $y^{\prime}$ for moderate negative values of $x$. (Clearly, there is also a problem at $y=0$; here, the derivative is pinned down by $y'=x/a$). I actually think I am nearing a proof of the result that involves considering many cases, though it is long and not elegant.

Comment: By "global" do you mean "on the entire $\mathbb R$", or just on $[0,+\infty)$?

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment. How to build a pseudo-global solution. Solving
$$y\left(x\right)=\frac{x-ay'\left(x\right)}{1+b y'\left(x\right)^{2}},$$ for $y'(x)$ we obtain

$$
y'(x) = \frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4b(x+y(x))y(x)}}{2by(x)}
$$

and the stream flow for each leaf is

[image]

for

$$
y'(x) = \frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+4b(x+y(x))y(x)}}{2by(x)}
$$

[image]

for

$$
y'(x) = \frac{-a-\sqrt{a^2+4b(x+y(x))y(x)}}{2by(x)}
$$

so for both leaves, the solutions converge asymptotically to a line. This line is determined as follows:

$$
y_{\infty}'(x) = \frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4b(x+y_{\infty}(x))y_{\infty}(x)}}{2by_{\infty}(x)}=c
$$

then

$$
y_{\infty}(x) = \frac{x-a c}{1+b c^2}
$$

but $y'_{\infty}(x)=c$ then $c$ is determined by the solutions of

$$
\frac{1}{1+b c^2}=c
$$

and thus, given such $c = c_{\infty}$ the pseudo-global solution is given by

$$
y_{\infty}(x) = \frac{x-a c_{\infty}}{1+b c_{\infty}^2}
$$

NOTE

The graphics where build for $a=b=1$ without boundary conditions consideration. Follows a MATHEMATICA script showing those facts.

```
Clear[a, b]
ode[y_, x_] := (1 + b D[y, x]^2) y - (x - a D[y, x])
sols = Solve[1/(1 + b c^2) == c, c][[1]]
flin = (x - a c)/(1 + b c^2) /. sols
ode[flin, x] // FullSimplify

(* 0 *)
```

There is a region, highlighted in red, where the left leaf can join the right leaf by sharing a common point.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be the linear solution that I mentioned in the question, unless I have missed something. In fact, if you look for a point where the left and right leaves meet and have equal derivatives (as required for a smooth solution), it has to be the unique point of intersection between the red and blue curves shown in your final plot. Moreover, I was able to prove only the linear solution passes through this point. Thus, only the linear solution can satisfy one leaf on one region and the other leaf on another region.

Comment: Hence, I guess my question is how to prove that just focusing on one leaf, you cannot get a global solution. I was able to do so in a very involved way that is too detailed to present as an answer here by considering many cases. I was not sure if there is an easier approach.

Comment: The found $y_{\infty}(x)$ is global. The only problem here, is that this solution is tangent to the feasible ode boundary. This fact, greatly complicates the numerical integration to obtain it, given the boundary condition. So formally $y_{\infty}(x)$ is a global solution with an unique boundary condition.

Comment: Yes, but isn't $y_\infty$ the linear solution that I mentioned in the original question?

Comment: I showed how I obtained that solution, which was not stated in the question...